# Delegate TabBar from custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, uitabbar

I have created a custom cell with a specific list of properties, including UITabBar. This cell has its specific Class called `RecomandationCell`, where I have declared these properties.

I use this custom cell to created multiple cells with different objects, also I want to know when I click an item of this tab bar in a specific row call its method that comes from Delegation of `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` which is

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if (item.tag==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Likes Clicked");
    }
    if (item.tag==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Comments Clicked");
    }
    if (item.tag==2)
    {
        NSLog(@"Shares Clicked");
    }
    if (item.tag==3)
    {
        NSLog(@"Add Clicked");
    }
    if (item.tag==4)
    {
        NSLog(@"Ratings Clicked");
    }
}
```

The problem is that this method won't be fired because I don't know where to delegate it, and even If I delegate it I don't know which tab bar at a specific index was clicked.

[image: This image shows graphically what I am trying to do]

RecomandationCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface RecomandationCell : UITableViewCell <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *wineImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *wineName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wineYear;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *socialTabBar;

@end
```

RecomandationCell.m

```
#import "RecomandationCell.h"

@implementation RecomandationCell
@synthesize socialTabBar;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if (item.tag==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Likes Clicked");
    }
    if (item.tag==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Comments Clicked");
    }
    if (item.tag==2)
    {
        NSLog(@"Shares Clicked");
    }
    if (item.tag==3)
    {
        NSLog(@"Add Clicked");
    }
    if (item.tag==4)
    {
        NSLog(@"Ratings Clicked");
    }
}
@end
```

RecomandationViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RecomandationCell.h"

@interface RecomandationViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDataSource,RecommandationCellDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *winesTable;

@end
```

RecomandationViewController.m

```
#import "RecomandationViewController.h"
#import "RecomandationCell.h"

@interface RecomandationViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecomandationViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *rowArray;

    //Titles for wine properties
    NSMutableArray *wineNames;
    NSMutableArray *wineProductors;
    NSMutableArray *winePlaces;
    NSMutableArray *wineYears;
    NSMutableArray *wineRatings;

    //Badges for Tab Bar items
    NSMutableArray *nrOfRatings;
    NSMutableArray *nrOfLikes;
    NSMutableArray *nrOfComments;
    NSMutableArray *nrOfShares;
    NSMutableArray *addToWishLists;

}
@synthesize winesTable,segmentView;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    rowArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"picture1.jpg",@"picture2.jpg",@"picture3.jpg",@"image4.jpeg",@"image5.jpeg",@"image6.jpeg", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
//    return rowArray.count;
    return 6;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mainCell";


    RecomandationCell *cell = [self.winesTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;

    cell.wineImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    cell.wineImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[rowArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [[cell.socialTabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]setBadgeValue:@"2"];
    [[cell.socialTabBar.items objectAtIndex:1]setBadgeValue:@"3"];
    [[cell.socialTabBar.items objectAtIndex:2]setBadgeValue:@"4"];
    [[cell.socialTabBar.items objectAtIndex:4]setBadgeValue:@"19"];


    cell.wineYear.text = @"2014";
    cell.wineName.text = @"Alex\nMandi\nTirana\nOK";



    return cell;
}


@end
```

Any suggestions or if you need more information don't hesitate to comment

Comment: So did you set the cell as the tab bar delegate?

Comment: I have set the cell.delegate = self at the other method. The class for UITableViewCell has no viewDidLoad and I don't where to start it.

Comment: Tell me what you want to do.. App flow.

Comment: @rajath I want to fire up the method tabbar didSelectItem when I click in a specific tabbar item in any row.

Comment: why you are using tab bar inside cell, use button in view and create action for each button, It will work better. UITabBarControllerDelegate  methods are called by UITabBarController, but you don't have tab bar controller.

Comment: @rajath I need to use tab bar because Its required to do it with it. I have used it with buttons and I can make it work, but my question wasn't this.

Comment: you can create direct action method to bar button itself from nib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oky u can do like this

in `CustomCell.h`

```
 @interface CustomTabedCell : UITableViewCell<UITabBarDelegate>//confirms to delegate
```

in `CustomCell.m` file

```
  #import "CustomTabedCell.h"

  @implementation CustomTabedCell

  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    UITabBarItem *firstItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"1" image:nil tag:10];//you can specify image hear i put nil 
    UITabBarItem *secondItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"2" image:nil tag:11]; // ... give tag number
    UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70)]; //leave this if u are added in xib
    tabBar.delegate = self; //delegate to custom cell itself
    tabBar.tag = 100;//leave
    tabBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstItem,secondItem, nil];//add to tab bar
    [self.contentView addSubview:tabBar];

   }
  return self;
 }

  //in custom cell u are getting the delegate call's

 - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
  {
    if (item.tag==10) //compare using tages as u added to tabed bar
     {
        NSLog(@"Likes Clicked");
     }
     if (item.tag==11)
    {
       NSLog(@"Comments Clicked");
    }
    if (item.tag==12)
    {
       NSLog(@"Shares Clicked");
    }
    if (item.tag==13)
   {
      NSLog(@"Add Clicked");
   }
   if (item.tag==14)
   {
       NSLog(@"Ratings Clicked");
   }
 }
```

after this u can call custom delegate method to controller for further processing

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, with some changes by defining the indexPath.row as a tag for every tab bar created at TableView

Answer (score 0):

First: You have specified `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in the interface for the cell, when you probably wanted to specify `UITabBarDelegate`.

Second: You set the delegate when you create the tabbar. Your provided code does not show this. You need to init the tabbar somewhere, and then you set a delegate on it.

Third: The place to setup something specific in a cell would be in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the tableviewcontroller.

Fourth: To get the index of the tapped tabbar-item, you can do that in the `didSelectItem` method:

```
NSUInteger indexOfTab = [[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item];
NSLog(@"Tab index = %u", indexOfTab);
```

Comment: You are still using UITabBarControllerDelegate... The method didSelectItem belongs to the UITabBarDelegate. And you are not initializing the uitabbar when creating the cell. You are setting the delegate to be the uitableviewcontroller, when you probably want it to be the cell that contains it. Both can work, but there should be a separation of concern. Can you edit your question and state what you want to happen when you tap a tab bar item? That said; I am not sure why you insist on using a UITabBar...